# MS PowerPoint distorted an imported svg image

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, svg

I have created an SVG image via Inkspace and I imported it in Powerpoint via drag and drop. I have resized and cropped it as well. I opened the PowerPoint file which included the SVG after some days and I noticed that the arrows in the SVG image have been modified (see 2nd image). How can I fix it and why it happened only to the arrows and not anywhere else?

I know I can delete and import it again but I am going to import many SVG files, thus this approach is not efficient.

Original SVG which I just imported to Powerpoint.
[image]

Modified SVG by the PowerPoint (the arrows have been cropped (see green rectangles). I have imported the red rectangles to highlight the upper and low parts of the slide using animation. They are not part of the problem.

[image]

Comment: Would it be feasible to take a screenshot of the SVG, and save it as PNG or JPEG, before importing it into PowerPoint?

Comment: Yes, that's a workaround but I would like to zoom in that image during my presentation and I do not want the image to look distorted.

Comment: Try to open SVGs in other Picture tools and try to export new copies in other standards of SVG. Then insert them into PowerPoint slides to have a check?

Comment: I only know illustrator for vector Analysis but I do not have this software on my laptop. What else would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem and am satisfied with below

- Step 1: Open the .svg in GIMP, select a high resolution and size
- Step 2: Save image as .png in good quality
- Step 3: Move into whichever program you like